# Array of unique elements but with a condition-

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of integers (NSMutable array to be exact), now i want the array to have unique elements, but there is a catch.

Condition-1. If there are 2 (even number of )elements that are similar then both the elements need to be deleted.
Condition-2.  If there are 3(odd number of) elements then only 1 element shall remain in the array.

am having a bit of a problem trying to solve it.
I have tried to loop around the array with 2 temporary variables

```
 for(int i =1;i<[tagArray count];i++){
    int temp1 = [[tagArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    int temp2 = [[tagArray objectAtIndex:i-1] intValue];
    if(temp1==temp2){

        [tagArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[tagArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [tagArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",tagArray);
    }
}
```

This code works but, when there are a lot of elements in the array the output i get is not the desired one.
P.S- the array is already being filled up randomly so i took the liberty of sorting it first.

1 more thing. please dont say abt set, i want unique elements but when i use SET see condition1 and 2. i cant perform those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. sort array (by ascending or descending intValue)
2. loop through each element (from 0 to N-1) and count number of previous equals elements (write it to equalNumbersCount).
3. After current number becomes not equal to previous, look at `equalNumberCount` and remove necessary number of elements (if this count is > 1 and even, remove all, if it's odd, remove only `equalNumberCount - 1` previous elements)
4. Reset equalNumberCount to 0.

Something like this. Tested and seems to work fine:

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [@[@1, @4, @4, @2, @2, @3, @3, @3, @4, @4, @5] mutableCopy];
    arr = [[arr sortedArrayWithOptions:NSSortStable usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [obj1 compare:obj2];
    }] mutableCopy];

    uint countOfEqualElements = 1;
    for (uint i = 1; i < arr.count; i++) {
        NSNumber *n1 = arr[i-1];
        NSNumber *n2 = arr[i];
        if ( [n2 isEqualToNumber:n1]) {
            countOfEqualElements++;
        }
        else if (countOfEqualElements > 1){
            uint numToRemove = countOfEqualElements % 2 == 0 ? countOfEqualElements : countOfEqualElements - 1;
            countOfEqualElements = 1;
            NSRange r;
            r.length = numToRemove;
            r.location = i - numToRemove;
            NSIndexSet * is = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:r];

            [arr removeObjectsAtIndexes:is];
            i -= numToRemove;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I've not tested with other elements yet, at present I think this might atleast interest you.

```
NSArray *localArray = @[@"1",@"23",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"5",@"9",@"1",@"11",@"10",@"1",@"23",@"3"];
NSCountedSet *countedSet= [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:localArray];

NSMutableArray *arrayToCheck = [localArray mutableCopy];
for (id obj in [localArray mutableCopy])
{
   if([countedSet countForObject:obj]==2)
   {
       [arrayToCheck removeObject:obj inRange:NSMakeRange([[localArray mutableCopy] indexOfObject:obj], [arrayToCheck count]-[[localArray mutableCopy] indexOfObject:obj])];
   }
    else if ([countedSet countForObject:obj]==3)
    {
       [arrayToCheck removeObject:obj inRange:NSMakeRange([[localArray mutableCopy] indexOfObject:obj], [arrayToCheck count]-[[localArray mutableCopy] indexOfObject:obj])];
        [arrayToCheck addObject:obj];
    }
}
localArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrayToCheck];
NSLog(@" array is %@",localArray);
```

Comment: Nope not working, as i said if there are even terms of objects
such as 2- 5's as here, both must get deleted.